# Python matplotlib fails to draw the Acnode (isolated point) on the Elliptic Curve y^2+x^3+x^2=0

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm using the below code to draw the ECC curve `y^2+x^3+x^2 =0`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
def main():
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    y, x = np.ogrid[-2:2:1000j, -2:2:1000j]
    ax.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), pow(y, 2) + pow(x, 3) + pow(x, 2) , [0],colors='red')

    ax.grid()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is

[image]

The expected image, however, is this

[image]

As we can see, the isolated point at (0,0) is not drawn. Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems as if a contour consisting of a single point is not displayed. One workaround could be to plot the point explicitly:
`plt.plot(0, 0, color = "red", marker = "o", zorder = 10, markersize = 2.5)`. Alternatively, the contours could be shifted slightly, e.g. to `z=0.0002` (instead of `z=0`), which practically does not change the contour shape (but displays the single point). Another variant would be to display the point as a separate contour and shift only this (then the rest is guaranteed to remain unchanged).

Comment: @Topaco I've looked at the ogrid points, and `0,0` is not listed. Yes, I thought to draw the point myself, however, this can mislead me and others. For this curve, we know that there is an acnode, what if we don't know. How can draw the curve more reliable. I've increased the `j`'s, that doesn't help either. I think I don't know about setting the `z=0.0002`.

Comment: I also tried to choose a step size so that the point 0,0 is included, e.g. with 1001j. But this didn't solve the problem. Sure, the best solution would be if the application indicates such points in some way by itself. Maybe there is such an option (the library has many parameters), but I didn't find a setting (however, I don't know this library very well either). You can also use a masked array, i.e. the points in question are masked, and implicitly marked when displayed. But again, you need to know the points already, which isn't what you want (nor is it really necessary for a single point).

Comment: @Topaco the draws are used [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/86884/18298), FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, it seems that a single point is not displayed as a contour. The best solution would be if the application indicates such points in some way by itself. Perhaps the library allows this, but I have not found a way and therefore show two workarounds here:

**Option 1:**

The isolated point at (0,0) could be marked explicitly:

```
ax.plot(0, 0, color="red", marker = "o", markersize = 2.5, zorder = 10)
```

In the case of multiple points, a masked array is a good choice, [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_corner_mask.html#contour-corner-mask).

[image]

**Option 2:**

The plot can be slightly varied around z = 0, e.g. z = 0.0002:

```
z = pow(y,2) + pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 3)
ax.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z, [0.0002], colors='red', zorder=10)
```

This will move the whole plot. Alternatively, the area around the isolated point alone could be shifted (by adding a second `contour` call with a small x,y grid around the isolated point at (0,0)). This does not change the rest.

[image]